# Reading a SEG-Y file with EBCDIC and binary data contents in Fortran

Tags: file, binary, fortran, ebcdic

I am reading a [SEG-Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEG-Y) file (used in geophysics to store data) which has 2 header sections, the first is 3200 bytes containing information in EBCDIC format, while the second header is in binary format and is 400 bytes length. The data later follows where the size of the data is determined by a number defined in the binary header defined in given byte locations 3217-3218.

I managed to read the EBCDIC (bytes 1-3200) header using simple open command in Fortran 90 with no access or format definitions, but I can't go further to read the specific bytes in the binary header (3201-3204, 3205-3206, ... and so on) which contains important information needed to read the rest of the binary data afterwards.

How to properly define the access/formatting for the file to successfully read everything at once? Does Fortran support changing the file access/format/... within a code? If this is not possible, how then I can skip the first 3200 bytes and move to the binary section (bytes 3201-3600) to read the data I need?

Comment: Welcome, remember to take the Welcome [tour]. What kind of compiler and operating system do you use? Which version?

Comment: Did you read anything about the `stream` access in Fortran 2003? Does your compiler support it?

Comment: I am GNU fortran compiler and I am operating on a Linux machine. Not sure if this compiler supports Fortran2003.

Comment: You mean gfortran? It does. Even very old gfortran versions do support stream access.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the data-file with `access="stream"`, you can read the file byte by byte from any position you want.

```
character :: byte   ! integer(int8) might be a better type

open(11, file="filename",access="stream",form="unformatted",action="read",status="old")

!be careful, the positions are numbered from 1, not from 0
read(11, pos=3200) byte
```

You can also read other datatypes if they are stored there in a compatible binary format

```
integer :: i
...
read(11, pos=...) i
```

On a little-endian machine you may have to convert their endianness.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I defined the open as per your request, but I am confused about the the pos=3200 in your read statement. This is giving me @ character. I want to read the following byte locations and all of them has to give me an integer number: 3201-3204, 3205-3208, 3209-3212, 3213-3214, and so on.

Comment: You must adjust the 3200 to the correct number, I don't know the structure of your file. It is the number of the byte you are reading counting from 1. It will NOT read it as EBCDIC, but as a native character (likely ASCII).  Just treat it like a byte. You can read a 1-byte integer instead of the character, but those are signed.

Comment: I managed to read the first EBCDIC header of 3200 bytes length using the read statement above. I have checked with a software that loads the same seg-y file and they are identical. Next, I read the first bytes of the next data block of binary header and I compared with what the software reads and they are unfortunately not the same (all of them are 2 or 4 byte integers). Any tips on how to sort this out?

Comment: Check the endianness/byte-order https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness  You may need to read the bytes into the integer in the right order or swap them after reading. I have some functions for byte swapping in https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/36580b7630617f25eaba7d34547eeef96f7180bc/src/endianness.f90?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Thanks for replying. Intel Fortran compiler offers options for byte swap in the open command as convert='big_endian' or convert='little_endian'. I have tried this option for big endian on the GNU Fortran compiler I use and this sorted out my problem. Many thanks